# String.split, пустые строки и сравнение

Tags: java, android

Не могу понять, в `idea / swing` проблем не было, в `android studio` при делении слова через split("") появляются пустые строки, перепробовал уже массу вариантов, запутался окончательно, в итоге чую, что хожу по кругу.

Подскажите, как одно привести к другому, что бы можно было сравнить:

```
String s = "дракон";
String[] array = {"д","р","а","к","о","н"};
```

Comment: Нет в этом примере пустых строк: `System.out.println(Arrays.asList("дракон".split(""))); // [д, р, а, к, о, н]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно привести массив в строку и сравнивать строки:

```
String s = "дракон";
String[] array = {"д","р","а","к","о","н"};

System.out.println(
    String.join("", array).equals(s)
);
// true
```

Comment: Действительно. Стыдно. Спасибо большое, глаз уже замылился.

Comment: @Freijer, бывает :)

Answer (score 1):

Не надо изобретать велосипед! Каждую строку в `Java` можно представить в виде массива символов:

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("дракон".toCharArray()));

// [д, р, а, к, о, н]
```